# Directus | Option to maintain a default columns in list view of Entity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directus, directus-flows

In Directus, while adding data to Entity( example: Template ), We have a list view, in which we can view the list of templates in table view.
[image]

There is an option to add columns in the list view, but this columns are currently added to table by current user and its saved as current user preference.

[image]

Do we have any option to configure this default columns for all the users from Data model or User based or Role based configuration by Admin user.
So that we can maintain the list view of Table to have same columns for all users example Template ID, Template Name, Short Description, Status.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for this, but it was easier than I thought.

You don't have to do any coding.
Just go to **Settings > Presets & Bookmarks**

There create a preset for each Entity / Data model that you want to set a default layout for, in the field name be sure to leave it blank so it is the default layout.

And then set the ***Scope***, to **Global: all users**

Choose a layout like "Table"  and in the layout preview choose the fields that you want to show as default.

Comment: Thank you @Dahngeek. I have created another question related to directus flows. Please check it and share your thoughts. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75614191/directus-flows-are-not-updating-the-revision-while-creating-a-collection