# Directus | Flows are not updating the Revision while creating a collection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directus, headless-cms, directus-flows

I'm using Directus lastest version 9.*.*

1. I have created a Data Model "Article" with title and Random_order field.

[image]

[image]

2. I have created a directus flow, which will update a random number into the field "Random order".

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. The feature is working fine but when i saw the revision history, that revision history is not showing any details about "Random_order" value. It should show the random number 535 for field "Random Order".

[image]

[image]

So the problem is when we use Directus flow to alter the field value of any Data model, then its not getting recorded in Revision history.

Currently i'm using the "Filter" type of Directus Flow

Comment: Just so you know I use the above as a manual for setting up a Script Operation. You saved me a day, keen to buy you a beer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised an issue (https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/17677). Directus Team has fixed this issue and its working fine in latest directus version 9.26.